# Twilio Video MediaStreamTrack TypeError with Cordova

Tags: cordova, twilio, webrtc, cordova-plugins, twilio-video

I’m developing a video live streaming app with Cordova using Twilio video conferencing. I’m trying to stream video from the device front-facing camera. It works well Android but I'm facing some issues on iOS.

I’m using a cordova-plugin-iosrtc plugin to expose the navigator.mediaDevices API

on the connect method I get this error

`TypeError: track must be a LocalAudioTrack, LocalVideoTrack, LocalDataTrack, orMediaStreamTrack`

I changed the code to the required track type

```
const { LocalAudioTrack, LocalVideoTrack, connect } = require('twilio-video');

constmediaStream = awaitnavigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints); 

const tracks = mediaStream.getTracks().map(track => track.kind === 'audio' ? newLocalAudioTrack(track) :newLocalVideoTrack(track)); const room = awaitconnect('token', { tracks });
```

and I get this error after the change

`TypeError: Argument 1 ('track') to mediaStream.addTrack must be an instance of MediaStreamTrack and sometimes this one => typeError undefined isn't an object (evaluating 'tracks.id')`

**Thanks In Advance I appreciate any kind of help**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cordova IOS compiled version doesn't stream the same media stream track types as same as Safari does on Web, I switched to Capacitor.js and worked with its plugins but still, that didn't work with me.

As far as this issue it will not work with Cordova `cordova-plugin-iosrtc` and we postponed this feature in our app

Comment: I am having the same problem and I cannot clearly understand your answer. Can you please explain in more detail that what do you mean by switching to `Capacitor.js`? I am already on Capacitor and tried the above solution provided by philnash, but still no luck.

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

When you have `MediaStreamTrack` objects, you can [pass them directly to `Video.connect` through the options](https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/video/releases/1.19.2/docs/global.html#ConnectOptions). So, you can do something like this:

```js
const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints);

const room = await Video.connect(token, { tracks: stream.getTracks() })
```

This will turn your `MediaStreamTrack`s into `LocalTrack`s without you having to worry about it.

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: Hi @philnash,
thanks for your answer, I did that previously and tried one more time  now, still not working and throw this error
```
TypeError: track must be a LocalAudioTrack, LocalVideoTrack, LocalDataTrack, orMediaStreamTrack
```
any Idea?

Comment: Can you inspect the type of the tracks returned by `stream.getTracks()`? Perhaps the Cordova plugin is creating something else?

Comment: I tried to inspect the track type but the XCode console logging object "js", also XCode is not interactive just black and white text, if you know a way that I can get the real track type, please tell me

Comment: in the plugin source code I think "if what I understand right" it's of type **RTCMediaStreamTrack** here's the log from XCode console, I logged the track, I hope it will make any sense, Thanks for your kind Phil
`[arg:[{"_listeners":{},"id":"B38F4F9B-9880-4EE9-8386-4FCF30EE037A","kind":"audio","label":"B38F4F9B-9880-4EE9-8386-4FCF30EE037A","muted":false,"readyState":"live","_enabled":true,"_ended":false},{"_listeners":{},"id":"29210470-49EA-43D7-8CD3-DD06DFBD855C","kind":"video","label":"29210470-49EA-43D7-8CD3-DD06DFBD855C","muted":false,"readyState":"live","_enabled":true,"_ended":false}]]`

Comment: As far as I can see, the plugin returns [its own implementation of `MediaStreamTrack`](https://github.com/cordova-rtc/cordova-plugin-iosrtc/blob/master/js/MediaStreamTrack.js). Perhaps that isn't passing the test for object type that Twilio Video is using. Have you considered trying a Cordova plugin specifically for Twilio Video, like this one: https://github.com/okode/cordova-plugin-twilio-video ?

Comment: to be honest, nope I didn't give it a try even I saw it, cause the IOSRTC usage example works on my app, and it has good stars and used by apps,
so I will give this twilio-cordova-video a try and response you with the result
Thanks for your Kind @philnash